# unable run restfull webservice in java while connecting to sqlsever

Tags: java, sql-server, json, web-services, jdbc

I am trying to call a web service that returns data from my sqlsever database in json format

This my code to get data from sqlsever and convert it to a json.
Here a function `getAllDataJson()` returns a String value of the result.
This is working fine when i call it to display as

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase();
System.out.println(db.getAllDataJson);
```

but it is not working when i call it from a webservice (This webservice configuration is also fine, i used this webservice to return json String before there it worked fine)

if i combine these both it is showing error in the function `getAllData()` (which is in the below return code)
at the line:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from persons");
```

it is showing nullPointerException
[It is showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Wjx.png)

The same error  is not there if run it as java application, it is only there when i am running on webservice

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

public class SqlDatabase {
    private static final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
        "databaseName=FIRST;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

private void connectToDb(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);           
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("error occured at Database Connection");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found");
    }
}


void closeDb(){
    try{
        if(con != null){con.close();}
        if(stmt!=null){stmt.close();}
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("error occured while closing Database Connection");
    }
}


public ResultSet getAllData(){
    ResultSet rs = null;
    connectToDb();
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from persons");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("error occured while getting data");
    }
    return rs;  
}

public String getAllDataJson() throws JSONException{

    ResultSet rs = getAllData();
    if(rs == null){return null;}

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject json = null;

    //data to json
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
            for(int i = 1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){
                json = new JSONObject();                    

                json.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
            }
            jArray.put(json);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("near Json");
    }

    return jArray.toString();
}


}
```

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions, and the try to use the connection anyway. At minimum log the `SQLException` that occurred (or use `e.printStackTrace()`) so we know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See at your DB host URL `dbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433`

It says `localhost`. Means it will always checks for DB server installed in the same machine where it is getting executed.

Check the DB server and web server are installed in the same machine. If not instead localhost you better to use IP address. Replace the localhost with the IP of DB server running.

Assume the IP of the system where DB server is running is `182.10.10.45` then

```
dbc:sqlserver://182.10.10.45:1433
```